# Context Manager that handles exceptions

Tags: python, contextmanager

I am trying to wrap my head around how to write a context manager that deals with writing some logs while handling any exceptions. The problem I am trying to solve is to make code like this:

```
try:
    # code that can raise exception here
except Exception as e:
    print('failed', e)

print('all good')
```

This is a repeated pattern I have in the code and I think it's best handled with a context manager like:

```
with my_ctx_manager(success_msg='all good', failed_msg='failed):
    # code that can raise exception here
```

this looks much better, but I don't know how to write the actual context manager to deal with any exceptions that could rise inside the context.

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def my_ctx_manager(success_msg, failed_msg):
   try:
       # if no exception then print(success_msg)
       # How do I catch any exception here
   except Exception:
      print(failed_msg)
      # I need the exception to propagate as well
      raise
```

I guess my question is more of the type: How do I make sure that the context manager correctly catches, logs and re-raise any exception for the code that is wrapping ?

Comment: Do you want the body of the `with` statement to execute in its entirety if an exception is raised in the middle, or simply catch the exception and continue after the `with` statement?

Comment: I know I am too late but this might help:
https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The way the [`@contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator works, you should write `yield` once within your context manager function, so that the `with` block will be executed while the `yield` statement pauses your function's execution. That means if the `with` block throws an exception, you can catch it by wrapping `yield` in a `try`/`except` block:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def example():
    print('entered the context manager')
    managed_resource = 'some resource'
    try:
        yield managed_resource
    except Exception as e:
        print('caught:', e)
        # any cleanup that should only be done on failure
        raise
    else:
        # any cleanup that should only be done on success
        print('no exception was thrown')
    finally:
        # any cleanup that should always be done
        print('exited the context manager')

with example() as resource:
    print('resource:', resource)
    raise ValueError('some error message')
```

Output:

```
entered the context manager
resource: some resource
caught: some error message
exited the context manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: some error message
```

If you want to catch everything (not just `Exception`), then you can write a bare `except:` block and use [`sys.exc_info()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238360/how-to-save-traceback-sys-exc-info-values-in-a-variable) to get the exception information.

Comment: Also want to add that if you don't have a resource to `yield`, then an empty yield statement works as well

Comment: I'd never seen `else:` after a `try:` block -- If you're more used to exception handling in i.e. java, could just put the "cleanup that should only be done on success" code on the line after `yield`

Comment: @CarlWalsh Yes; for clarity, the use of `else` in Python is that it happens after the `try` and only on success, but any exceptions thrown in the `else` block won't be caught by the preceding `except` block. So an exception raised during cleanup won't be treated the same as an exception raised in the external `with` block.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using `contextmanager`, which I find a bit clunky for this task (you need to fake a generator with a yield just to log an exception), write a context manager yourself. Its simply a class with two special methods. And with the predefined `AbstractContextManager` you only need to implement one of them:

```
import contextlib

class ExceptionLogger(contextlib.AbstractContextManager):

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_type:
            print("***Logging exception {}***".format((exc_type, exc_value, 
                traceback)))

with ExceptionLogger():
    raise ValueError("foo")
```